# Caching Hibernate Native Query - How can I set the max time to Live for a specifc query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, caching

Hi I am using the EHCache to cache the SQL results from some Hibernate Native Queries in a JPA app. I am wondering how I can set for a specific query how long the results should should be cached? i.e. to 24h but for other queries not?

Hibernate Properties

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

EHCache Config XML

```
<ehcache>
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
  <defaultCache
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="120"
     timeToLiveSeconds="120"
     maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
     diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
     memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
     <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
  />
</ehcache>
```

Java Method in a Spring Repository Class

```
@Repository
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class AnalyticsRepositoryImpl implements AnalyticsRepository {

   public Map<Long, Long> getAgeStatistic(boolean onlyPaid) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT (date_part('year',current_date) - date_part('year',a.date_value))  as age, COUNT(u.id) as count from answers a ");
    sb.append("JOIN ...");
    ...
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());

    // enable the cache for the native query
    NativeQuery nativeQuery = q.unwrap(NativeQuery.class);
    nativeQuery.addScalar("age", IntegerType.INSTANCE);
    nativeQuery.addScalar("count", LongType.INSTANCE);
    nativeQuery.setCacheable(true);

    List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();

    // Place results in map
    Map<Long, Long> map = convertResultSetToLongKeyMap(result);

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the solution is for my problem to use "cache regions". so you can define a own region for your queries

e.g. set the "analytics" cache region

```
@Repository
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class AnalyticsRepositoryImpl implements AnalyticsRepository {

   public Map<Long, Long> getAgeStatistic(boolean onlyPaid) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT (date_part('year',current_date) - date_part('year',a.date_value))  as age, COUNT(u.id) as count from answers a ");
    sb.append("JOIN ...");
    ...
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString());

    // enable the cache for the native query
    NativeQuery nativeQuery = q.unwrap(NativeQuery.class);
    nativeQuery.addScalar("age", IntegerType.INSTANCE);
    nativeQuery.addScalar("count", LongType.INSTANCE);
    nativeQuery.setCacheable(true);

    nativeQuery.setCacheRegion("analytics");

    List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();

    // Place results in map
    Map<Long, Long> map = convertResultSetToLongKeyMap(result);

    return map;
}
```

and in the ehcache configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

  <defaultCache
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="120"
     timeToLiveSeconds="120"
     maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
     diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
     memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
     </defaultCache>

   <cache name="analytics"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="6000"
    timeToLiveSeconds="6000">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```